# How many devices can be used simultaneously with one user account?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Is there a limitation of device number can be used with one user account?

If yes, how many devices can be used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to google in https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2736257?hl=en&ref_topic=14940 there is no limit.

there it says

> Google Drive, Gmail, and Google+ Photos give you 15 GB of storage space for free, so you can keep your files, emails, and photos **accessible from any device**, anywhere.